# Sorbet won't allow Zlib::GzipReader as a parameter to a method

Tags: ruby, generics, zlib, static-typing, sorbet

This [Ruby code with a Sorbet signature](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20params%28source%3A%20T.any%28String%2C%20Zlib%3A%3AGzipReader%29%29.returns%28T%3A%3ABoolean%29%20%7D%0Adef%20file%3F%28source%29%0A%20%20source.is_a%3F%28String%29%20%26%26%20File.exist%3F%28source.to_s%29%0Aend):

```
sig { params(source: T.any(String, Zlib::GzipReader)).returns(T::Boolean) }
def file?(source)
  source.is_a?(String) && File.exist?(source.to_s)
end
```

generates the following error:

```
Malformed type declaration. Generic class without type arguments Zlib::GzipReader https://srb.help/5045
```

[The revealed type](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20params%28source%3A%20T.any%28String%2C%20Zlib%3A%3AGzipReader%29%29.returns%28T%3A%3ABoolean%29%20%7D%0Adef%20file%3F%28source%29%0A%20%20T.reveal_type%28source%29%0A%20%20source.is_a%3F%28String%29%20%26%26%20File.exist%3F%28source.to_s%29%0Aend) for `source` is `Zlib::GzipReader[T.anything]` but if I [specify that](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20params%28source%3A%20T.any%28String%2C%20Zlib%3A%3AGzipReader%5BT.anything%5D%29%29.returns%28T%3A%3ABoolean%29%20%7D%0Adef%20file%3F%28source%29%0A%20%20source.is_a%3F%28String%29%20%26%26%20File.exist%3F%28source.to_s%29%0Aend) I get a different error:

```
 Method [] does not exist on T.class_of(Zlib::GzipReader)[Zlib::GzipReader[T.anything]] https://srb.help/7003
```

I think this is [the relevant line](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/af7d671b11fa1887d224dd4cecb13a0b5f366616/rbi/stdlib/zlib.rbi#L758) in `zlib.rbi` and it has something to do with [Covariance](https://sorbet.org/docs/generics#covariance-out) but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This has the same root cause as the one that prompted this PR upstream into Sorbet: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/6324

I think you can open a similar PR to fix the type variable of `Zlib::GzipReader` to `T.untyped` (or maybe even `String`, since `Zlib::GzipReader#each` seems to yield string instances to the supplied block).